# Missing logs - log4j.xml configuration seems to be ignored - Weblogic 9.2

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic, slf4j

I'm running WAR packed in EAR on **WebLogic 9.2**. My functionality is using **slf4j** to log using **log4j.xml** configuration. log4j.xml is in `resources` directory of `war` project, so it lands in `WEB-INF/classes` directory.

Everything was working under both **WebLogic 8** and **Weblogic 9.2** under Windows, however **WebLogic 9.2** under Linux is simply ignoring the file and no log file is created.

I've tested following modifications:

1. Removed directory name from `File` param to `RollingFileAppender`, leaving only file name
2. Both including and excluding `log4j` from war (scope `provided`)
3. Using `slf4j` version 1.5.10 with both `log4j` version 1.2.8 (from weblogic) and 1.2.12
4. Placing separate log4j.xml into `mydomain/conf` directory

However, none of them made log messages appear anywhere. Even `info` messages are not displayed in main log, however it is set for `info` messages, and on previous weblogic they were displayed also in main log.

What is worse, even `System.out` calls go to `null` and are displayed nowhere.

So, currently, I have no idea what is wrong because even no error message about log configuration is present. Can anyone help?

---

I've **update** a bit.

I've successfully set log4j.debug=true option for weblogic, and I've got communique: `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger`

But the log4j.xml file **is** present in `WEB-INF/classes`. I've additionally **added** it to `WEB-INF`. And it is and was working under Windows. So I don't know what causes the issue with finding this file under Linux.

---

**Update 2**
Logging **works** under Linux version of **WebLogic 9.2**. The problem is instance-specific. But I have still no idea what can be messed up in order to achieve such miseffect. In configuration in web console I see nothing suspicious.

Comment: Two things worth trying, just in case:  
1-Just for a matter of testing, add `<container-descriptor><prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes></container-descriptor>` to your `weblogic.xml` descriptor.  
2-Try to follow this [link](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=633).

Comment: I've added this container-description to my weblogic-application.xml (I have only him) and I've got validation error...

Comment: Unfortunately, this element is only valid on the weblogic.xml file. If you want to try, you can create a weblogic.xml file in the same place you have your weblogic-application.xml file.

Comment: I've updated the question, on my local weblogic 9.2 it is working, not working still on remote linux weblogic. But the other apps deployed there are logging normally, only mine not, and nobody knows why.

Answer (score 3):

I find this environment option invaluable: -Dlog4j.debug=true
It shows you how log4j initializes and where it looks for its configuration file.

Comment: If you haven't tried the above suggestion, you definitely should

Comment: Then how can you ever fix it? Just remember to add this option the next time you have a deploy/release slot and make a habit of always adding this option when using log4j.

Comment: How can I set this option for particular deploy using weblogic console? I thought it can be set only in weblogic startup script

Comment: I'm sorry I have no experience with Weblogic, but somewhere you have to able to define environment variables I would think

Comment: It is not the answer for the solution

Answer (score -1):

Well, after a talk with weblogic guru that send me to the a few million page weblogic documentation I've found out the solution:

**Never** user **log4j** under **weblogic**!

And, applying to that maxim, I've switched to **logback**.

And it is working! So much nerves and the solution was so simple... However, we've failed launching logback under **jBoss** using **slf4j**, so it is so server-specific :(

Comment: "Never use log4j under weblogic!" I think that's incorrect/unfair to say. It can work really well on WebLogic. We're doing just that in some of our applications.

Comment: This is just ignoring the issue and using another framework.